# How do I specify a web proxy when using RestEasy client proxy?

Tags: java, resteasy, webproxy

I am using a RestEasy ProxyFactory to connecting to a REST service.  However I need to connect via a web proxy.  How do I specify the proxy connection details?

At the moment I am creating the instance using:

```
MyInterface instance = org.jboss.resteasy.client.ProxyFactory.create(MyInterface.class,url);
instance.doStuff();
```

However, it does not connect.

RestEasy seems to be using Apache Commons HTTPClient under the covers, which does not allow you to specify a proxy using the standard Java System Properties.

Answer (score 3):

Ok I think I've found it by specifying the ClientExecutor:

```
org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.getHostConfiguration().setProxy(proxyHost,proxyPort);
ClientExecutor executor = new ApacheHttpClientExecutor(httpClient);
MyInterface instance = org.jboss.resteasy.client.ProxyFactory.create(MyInterface.class,url,executor);
```